# htaccess rewrite rule to include variable

Tags: .htaccess

I'm currently using this rewrite rule

`RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ ../new/index.php?product=$1`

which is located in the folder `/old` to make this

**sample.com/old/123**

forward to this

**sample.com/new/index.php?product=123**

---

I'd like to include another variable in this rule to make this

**sample.com/old/123?type=1**

forward to this:

**sample.com/new/index.php?product=123&type=1**

Can someone help me figure this put please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add `[QSA]` to the end of your RewriteRule, it should pass through any additional query strings to the new URL:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ ../new/index.php?product=$1 [QSA]
```